# v-on:click not working on button when clicking it's content in bootstrap-vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I have created in my vue component the following template

```
                <b-button v-on:click="check($event)" class="btn btn-success" data-action="consent">
                    <b-icon-check></b-icon-check>
                </b-button>
```

However the click event only seems to work if I click on the button itself, for example on the sides around the icon, and not when clicking on the icon itself.

I'm wondering if there's a better way to do what I want to achieve instead of adding another v-on:click on the icon itself.

Basically I want the button to trigger the click event even if any subelement it has is clicked.

[image]

Here's the function check(event)

```
    methods:{
        check(event){
            let action = event.target.getAttribute('data-action');
            if(action === 'consent'){
                this.checked = true;
            }
            else{
                this.checked = false;
            }
        }
    },
```

After reading the comments and the link for modifiers, I think my mistake is assuming that the `event.target` is going to be the button. Instead it's the icon itself that's why my code is failing.

Comment: It looks like something is stopping the icon from bubbling to the button, can you share the code of the `check` method?

Comment: Test the modifiers of v-on:  https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers

Comment: I just updated the question because I think the event is actually triggering but doesn't work because I'm working on the wrong event.target. But I'm wondering why it doesn't propagate to the button as well.

Comment: I've tested your code, and it did trigger the event when click on the icon

Comment: you missed `data-action` for the icon which fails `event.target.getAttribute('data-action')`  add `data-action="consent"` to the `<b-icon-check></b-icon-check>`

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to rewrite it to `@click="check('consent')"`, so you don't need the event target to get the `data-action` attribute?

Comment: True that would be much simpler, but I need the target as well to add some classes to it later on for styling purposes on each case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `event.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-action')` to grab the `data*` attribute from where the event listener is bound. `event.currentTarget` will always be the element the event listener is bound to (rather than the element that actually initiated the `click` event, which is what `event.target` points to).

Comment: I'll definitely try that and get back to you :)

Comment: Yep it was perfect. That's what I needed thank you very much